# Why is the US broadcast media mostly banned from fact-checking political advertising?

Tags: united-states, advertising, fact-checking

On this [site](https://mailchi.mp/ac1f6255038f/benedicts-newsletter-no-451001?e=7a3ec8a38b) the author writes:

> Two more Facebook moderation stories. On one hand, they're moving to block 'deep fake' manipulated video, but on the other, they're holding firm on not fact-checking ads placed by political candidates (note that US broadcast media is mostly banned from fact-checking political ads), instead focusing on vetting who places the ads and on providing transparency on what ads have been run.

This seems to go against [journalistic](https://libguides.usc.edu/c.php?g=234948&p=1559343) [principles](https://ifcncodeofprinciples.poynter.org/). (Not that a broadcaster is entirely about journalism.) My question is about where truth and integrity play into the decision-making process in an organisation that is making money.

My question is: **Why is the US broadcast media mostly banned from fact-checking political advertising?**

Comment: Where and by whom is this ban stipulated?

Comment: Who is “they” in your quote “...they’re holding firm on not fact-checking ads placed by political candidates...”?  Who is (mostly) banning the broadcast media from undertaking the fact checks?  The languages makes it sound like it is the US government that is doing the banning - if so, what’s the mechanism?

Comment: The quote is about facebook, but the question is about broadcast media. These are not the same thing. Facebook is not fact-checking political advertising so that its revenue is not impacted.

Comment: I was under the impression that no ads are being fact-checked in general, not just political ads, because most ads at the very least embellish the truth.

Comment: To illustrate what broadcast media *is* allowed to do, I once saw a local news broadcast do a story exposing the lies in a local candidate's ad.  *Immediately* following that segment was a commercial break where that *exact* ad aired (most likely just a coincidence).  They can't censor the ad itself, but there's nothing preventing them from fact-checking it through other avenues.

Comment: Which site is the quote from?

Comment: @Jontia The question is about US broadcast media; the quote is largely about Facebook yes but it's the part in the parenthetical (which is about the US broadcast media) that's relevant. You do have to read the _whole_ quote not just the first few words ;)

Comment: I had to delete some comments. Please note that comments should be used to debate how an answer could be improved. They should not be used for political debates or to answer the question. For more information on how comments should and should not be used, please review the help center article on the [commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Nothing prevents or bans the broadcast media from Fact Checking political advertising. But broadcasts are prevented from censoring political campaigns.

The issue has recently been investigated by [PolitiFact](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2019/oct/15/elizabeth-warren/phony-facebook-ad-warren-said-most-tv-networks-wil/) in the context of statements by Elizabeth Warren who stated that broadcast media was more robust on political advertising than Facebook. PolitiFact found they were not, and broadcasters would run a candidate's ad even if it contained false statements, based on federal law preventing censorship.

> Section 315 of the Federal Communications Act of 1934 states:
>
> "If any licensee shall permit any person who is a legally qualified candidate for any public office to use a broadcasting station, he shall afford equal opportunities to all other such candidates for that office in the use of such broadcasting station: Provided, That such licensee shall have no power of censorship over the material broadcast under the provision of this section."
>
> Broadcasters are bound by that act and therefore can’t reject a presidential candidate’s ad, even if contains false information. (The candidates do have to abide by disclosure rules to make it clear who paid for the ad.)

Facebook's position as described by [Mark Zuckerberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT9BRUoXhh8=1m45s) under House questioning, essentially expands this to all political advertising.

This doesn't mean that broadcasters can't fact check the ads run on their own or other networks. It is just that fact checking organisations are mostly digitally focused. But there are organisations trying to change this.

To reach a wider audience, expand fact-checking to [broadcast news](https://ijnet.org/en/story/reach-wider-audience-expand-fact-checking-broadcast-news).

> Fact-checkers just need to collaborate with broadcast organizations for a few minutes each week to reach more people. As part of my fellowship I set up a partnership between the News & Observer and two National Public Radio affiliates in North Carolina.

...

> As it is now, fact-checking reaches a small audience of well-informed people. To fight the growing problem of misinformation, fact-checkers must evolve their content by collaborating with broadcast media to reach a wider audience and continue to build trust among diverse audiences.

Comment: Aren't many ads run by PACs rather than candidates?  Does that mean they can selective refuse to broadcast those, because they're not run by candidates?

Comment: @gerrit that's true, the Politifact article says "The law does not apply to PACs or independent expenditure ads" and links to an instance of CNN rejecting a Trump ad containing [demonstrably false](https://www.thedailybeast.com/cnn-refuses-to-air-trump-ad-pushing-biden-ukraine-claims-and-bashing-network-anchors) Biden-Ukraine information.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please keep the comments relevant to the answer.

Comment: I would just add that the intent with these laws is that anyone should be able to run for president, and candidates shouldn't be censored to avoid arbitrarily applying those rules to favor a particular candidate. (How effectively it does that, and if the side effects are worth it is another matter)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that broadcast media is bound by rules that are not applied to print and digital mediums (and indeed would be considered a violation of the first amendment if they tried to), and *why* .

Comment: @RBarryYoung And to further clarify, the reason for these broadcast rules is that, as stated in answer, broadcasters are licensed by the state.

Comment: @paulj Licensing is just part of the rules that broadcast media is bound to that other media are not (and arguably can*not* be).  It does not constitute an explanation of that difference.

Answer (score 25):

The world is too complex and too many "facts" fall in a gray area. A famous saying is "**there are lies, damned lies, and statistics.**"

"*President Obama enjoyed 8 years of a declining deficit and steady standard of living increase.*"

Could be "proven" completely true, or false, based on how one might choose to measure the deficit and standard of living by adjusting for inflation, changes in forex rates, the basket of goods used to measure monthly expenses, the macro-implications of issuing debt in your own country's fiat currency, effect of undocumented workers on future wages and prices, etc. Adjusting for all these exogenous variables can be done completely arbitrarily so that one can reach whatever conclusion one wants.

And, I don't want to be pedantic, but I could say that the US has not fought any "wars" since 1945. "War" has a clear definition in the US Constitution. The last "war" was WW2. Korea? Vietnam? Iraq? From the perspective of the US homeland, those were not "wars" because minimal sacrifice was made on the home front and all the devastation was abroad and so, from US perspective, its a "gray area." Yet most Americans do consider them actual "wars." (yes. total bs. since ww2, the usa is always in a state of "war" somewhere as Eisenhower so presciently warned in his farewell address.)

For "fact checking", how precise should it be and who would decide (the censorship)?

Comment: I think most of these questions already have answers. Fact checking services do already exist. They're just online rather than in broadcast media. None of the points you raise would require a new solution. That said, clearing up these grey areas is one reason why online fact checking services are often technical and dry, a barrier to adoption mentioned in the article I linked previously.

Comment: `the US has not fought any war since 1945` - no, all that means is that US has not followed its own rules regarding war for the better part of the past century.  The US has certainly been involved in *lots* of wars.  Just because your internal political machine is rotten, and you want to believe fantasy stories or bureaucratic excuses more than the truth, doesn't mean you can stand up and say you don't participate in wars anymore.

Comment: Try to manipulate statistics yourself! [Hack Your Way To Scientific Glory](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/p-hacking/)

Comment: @xLeitix Capital-T Truth may or may not be relative, but information certainly is. Would you unquestioningly believe the abstract of a study without checking the methodology? And we're talking about *peer-reviewed science*, how do you plan to scale that to sound-bite journalism? Skeptics.SE is populated by people who are generally of, well, a skeptical bent, and higher than average intelligence. How do you plan to scale that format to broadcast media and the general population?

Comment: While the entire answer is true to the facts being presented, it doesn't actually answer the question.  The implication is certainly that it's difficult to fact-check political ads, which is valid, but the question is about why they aren't *allowed* to do so - not the impracticality of it.

Comment: @xLeitix On the other hand, you can also find lots of very poorly supported answers on Skeptics.SE that were massively upvoted because they hit HNQ and agreed with the biases of a lot of the 101 rep people who clicked through from HNQ. And, to be completely honest, the biases of the moderators there have some influence on this, too, since the moderation is more active there. The standards of skepticism applied in moderation actions to answers that agree with the average bias of the moderators tends to be less than those that don't, even though I don't think that's intentional.

Comment: @JaredSmith To quote Homer Simpson, "You can use facts to prove anything that's even remotely true. Facts schmacts!"

Comment: @Zibbobz true, but it's a pretty short leap to conclude that since it is in practice not possible that they are prohibited (to the extent they actually are) for that reason.

Comment: @JaredSmith if that's the case, then the answer would be greatly improved by an explicit statement to that effect - as it reads right now, it's basically an argument against fact-checking of any kind, which may be relevant but doesn't work well as an answer to the specific question.

Comment: @user312440 to be annoyingly pedantic:  the statement refers to whether Obama enjoyed a fact not whether the fact is true.  Since only Obama can know his enjoyment, only Obama can know the truth.  For example,  "Trump enjoyed the almost unanimous acclaim of the people in the 2016 election" is unknowable but probably true.  He did enjoy it.

Comment: @emory enjoy - transitive verb - 1. to have for one's use, benefit, or lot  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enjoy

Comment: @Zibbobz I don't disagree with you

Comment: This is an interesting piece of opinion about the meanings of truth and fact-checking, but I am not sure it really answer the question.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku alternatively enjoy (transitive) To receive pleasure or satisfaction from something

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't see a technical truth anywhere where Korea, Vietnam, Iraq, etc, are not wars.  I see a technical truth in formal war not having been *declared* in those cases, but the ensuing state of armed conflict nevertheless existed.  There is no perspective that can objectively deny that those armed conflicts happened.

Comment: @J... fair enough, but it's easy to alter the framing in such a way that the statement is technically true but actually false: "The United States has not declared war on anyone since 1945"...but try telling that to the North Koreans/North Vietnamese/Iraqis. I still contend that such was the point of the OP.

Comment: @JaredSmith OP's claim was that the US has not *fought* any wars since 1945.  That claim is significantly harder to defend.

Comment: @J... What is "war"? Is it just about soldiers? Regarding civilian participation, the Japanese in WW2 were fire-bombed while starving, and then torched by 2 nuclear weapons. For Americans that "war" was growing "Victory Gardens". The Iran / Iraq War and the US / Iraq War for the civilians were very different.  Iran was on the brink and using untrained near-children soldiers facing poison gas. The US / Iraq war was "shock / awe" on CNN for entertainment. US civilians have surely never "been to war".

Comment: @user312440 I'm not sure if you're being fatuous or not.  "War" is a state of armed conflict between organized groups of people.

Comment: @J... My final point was the dictionary definition of war is not much better than the Constitutional one. If only it were as simple as 2 countries' professional soldiers going mano-a-mano on a battlefield. The role of civilians can't be discounted because they're the raison d'être.

Comment: @user312440 I didn't say anything about countries, soldiers, or civilians.  Those are all organized groups of people, of course, so they all fit the general definition.  Certainly we can think of examples of civilians and soldiers organizing together in many different ways, in some cases pooling their resources to achieve a common objective.

Comment: I suggest this comment stream is used as an answer in its own right as one three letter word has incited this much discussion about the facts.  If broadcast companies attempted fact checking of political adverts then they would be tied up for years of litigation about censorship.

Comment: It's true that there is complexity in truth or falsehood, but fact checking sites have been dealing with this complexity for some time.  Given that there already exists sites that distinguish between 'technically true' and 'misleading or manipulative' statements It should be possible for broadcast media to do the same.  For example in theory one could simply site politifact rankings for dubious claims and advertise those ratings in media.  The law makes this difficult and it's not in the best interest of media so it won't happen, but it's not impossible to handle misleading 'truths'

Answer (score 6):

Bias is difficult to filter and some times, the information is not correctly known. For instance, President Trump claimed in March of 2017 that his campaign had been spied on by the intelligence community (FBI, etc). This was widely lampooned as not true, included by personnel that we now know in fact did the surveillance. So, it wasn't known correctly. Many members of the media criticized it. So, if given the chance, they would have incorrectly censored it.

Comment: Welcome to Politics! Please try to add references to support your answer.

Comment: who else could brag about their needing to be investigated?

Comment: @KevinMoore do you claim that Trump had evidence of, or valid grounds to believe in the spying, which he chose not to share at the time? If so, what reason do you believing this, and what reason do you give for him hiding the evidence. If not, then he was just making crap up, and censoring it would have been correct.

If someone makes stuff up all the time, and is sometimes coincidentally correct, that doesn't make the coincidentally-true fabrication any more valid than the rest.